# Editing Image in IceFaces

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I need to add different shapes and text for describing an image,I need to know is there any component in ICEfaces for that? If not is there any other approach available?
As I am new to JSF, I checked in Icefaces showcase but did not find the solution.I want something like paint where I can add different shapes and text to my image.
Please give me some suggestions in achieving this.

Comment: Please, add what have you tried so far. To make this question more specific

Comment: You can (and should) when using jsf still use plain html, javascript and css where applicable. Since what you need is pure client-side, search for a 'paint' framework in javascript and try to post the resulting image to the server with either jsf or rest.